# Android - two actions in app at the same time

Tags: android, multithreading, action

I am developing app and I need that my app will be doing two actions at the same time. For example - I can drag marker and the map will be scrolling at the same time.
I tried to update map while dragging marker, everything would be okay, except thing that when thread starts, maps starts scrolling continuously and I cand do anything more. Here is the code, I call it in `onCreate()` method.  I tried to do `Runnable` and `AsyncTask` and the results were the same. Any suggestions?

```
private void update() {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                  while (drag)
                                      mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(10, 0), 2, null);
                             }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }.start();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the code to interrupt your thread. That's why your map keep scrolling. Try to use drag event to drive this animation, and add some code to terminate the thread at some point.